# Ubuntu Deluge shows errors when downloading large bit torrent files and keeps erroring out after trying to resume

Tags: ubuntu, bittorrent, deluge

Ubuntu Deluge shows errors when downloading large bit torrent files and keeps erroring out after trying to resume.  The error on details shows: "Invalid argument".

This happens for many large torrents that are running for several days (trying to download.)  I try to "resume" and "force rechceck" but it never works.  Smaller torrents seem to work ok.  What is causing these torrents to never complete?  Is there a way to force Deluge to keep auto-resuming every few minutes after a failure instead of just giving up?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are trying to download a torrent that has a large file (more than 4 GB) and trying to save it on a FAT drive. FAT is limited in the file size. Use NTFS (if on Windows) or any Linux drive format (ext3 or ext4 or ...)

Answer (score 0):

I was with the same problem here (but using qbittorrent). I converted the partition to NTFS and the problem was solved.

Comment: That can't possibly have any relation to OP's problem.

Comment: I don't know. Maybe he's downloading to an external HD or another partition formated with FAT32. That was my case, as I have linux and windows installed in different partitions, I created a 3rd. partition for saving all the user files (films, music, etc). Since windows can't read any other format different of his own... that means = fat32 or NTFS.